# Deploy A War/Ear To Container Marked build As failure When Deploying To Tomcat 9 Server

Tags: jenkins, deployment, testing, maven

When I was Deploying A Sample Application On Tomcat9 I Faced This Issue.

This is the Tomact9 Users File where I added credentials do I need to add anything more,

[image: This is the Tomcat User XML File]

Is There Any Configuration Which I have do in Tomcat or In Jenkins
[image: Can Someone help Me Out With This]

What could be the point I might be missing? Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "manager-script" role in the roles section. I figured this out by googling:

> the username you used is not allowed to use the text based tomcat manager

and the first result was this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675813/the-username-you-provided-is-not-allowed-to-use-the-text-based-tomcat-manager-e).